# LINQ look up list of objs in datable of different objs that share a common property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have list A which is obj A and list B which is obj B.  Both list share one property and I want to look up all the obj B of list B has in A and pull them out.

So, ex.

List A is a bunch of people

List B is a bunch of names

Both list have a personId

Now I want to get all the people with the names that are in List B. I was thinking something like a:

```
class names 
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
}

class people
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
}

    var newList = new List<person>();

    foreach(var n in names)
    {
        var person = people.firstordefault(p => p.name == n);
        if(person!=null)
        {    
            newList.Add(person);
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering is there is a more efficent way with LINQ I can do this because it wont be a list everytime it might be the database im calling it from and i dont want to call the database a thousands for no reason.

This is probably a bad example if i think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This codes :

```
var newList = new List<person>();
foreach(var n in names)
{
    var person = people.firstordefault(p => p.name == n);
   if(person!=null)
   {    
      newList.Add(person);
   }
}
```

will produce the same result as :

```
var newList = new List<person>();
newList = people.Where(p => names.Contains(p.name)).ToList();
```

responding your update, if `names` is a list of `names` object instead of string, you can do as follow :

```
newList = people.Where(p => names.Select(o => o.name).Contains(p.name)).ToList();
```

Comment: This is really close to what I was looking for but what if names were a list of name objs and one of the properties is the string value that will be needed to match the p.name?

I updated my original question with the classes

Comment: change `names.Contains(p.name)` to `names.Select(o => o.stringProperty).Contains(p.name)`

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ, You can do this:

```
var intersection = ListA.Intersect(ListB);
```

**However**, this is the **set intersection**, meaning if ListA and ListB don't have unique values in it, you won't get any copies. In other words if you have the following:

```
var ListA = new [] { 0, 0, 1, 2, 3 };
var ListB = new [] { 0, 0, 0, 2 };
```

Then ListA.Intersect(ListB) produces:

```
{ 0, 2 }
```

If you're expecting:

```
{ 0, 0, 2 }
```

Then you're going to have to maintain a count of the items yourself and yield/decrement as you scan the two lists.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with two different classes, what you're really looking for is a join.

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>{new Person{Name = "Mark"}, 
                                       new Person{Name = "Alice"}, 
                                       new Person{Name = "Jane"}};

List<string> names = new List<string>{"Mark"};

var query = from p in people
            join n in names on p.Name equals n
            select p; // will output Person Mark
```

Note: This has time complexity of O(p+n) (where p = number of people and n = number of names), because join is implemented as a hash join. Your nested loop above or a Where/Contains LINQ query time complexity O(p*n), since it's iterating n for every p. This may or may not be an issue depending on the sizes of your collections.